# Eclipse Java Code Template -> Method Body: How do I insert a carriage return?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, methods

Basically, I wanted to edit the Method Body template so that whenever I clicked on "Add unimplemented method(s)..." in the tooltip, I would have my preferred method created with the template I wanted.

***For example (and all other general methods I use in the future):***

When I clicked on "Add unimplemented method(s)...", I usually get (DO NOT WANT):

```
@Override
public void render(Canvas c, float canvasX, float canvasY) {}
```

What I wanted is adding unimplemented method(s) automatically **with this pattern** (DO WANT):

```
@Override
public void render(Canvas c, float canvasX, float canvasY) {
}
```

Here's what the code template looks like currently:

[image: Diagram.]

How should I edit this, so I can get the pattern marked as "DO WANT" above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how you get the new line character into the method body, but you can always hit `CMD+SHIFT+F` to format the code according yo your style specification.

Comment: I'm on Windows. What it does, if I assumed CMD is Ctrl, is that it formats my code in the JAVA source file. I don't know how you are able to save the formatting that I wanted, if I use Ctrl+Shift+F?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

Go to

```
 Preferences
 >Java
  >Code Style
   >Formatter 
     > Edit
      > Braces Tab
         >Method Declaration
          > Change Option to Next Line
      > Line Wrapping 
          > Method Declarations
          > Declaration
           > Do Not Wrap
```

Also Please add following in `Method Body` settings

```
  // ${todo} Auto-generated method stub
  ${body_statement}
```

This will add a `**TODO**` that you remind you that you have auto generated the method and you need to add some code.

```
 Preferences
 >Java
  >Code Style
   >Code Template
    >Code
     >Method Body
      >Edit
       >Paste the value in pattern
```

Comment: There's no "New Line". If I tick "Next Line", it will cause the first bracket to go onto the next line, along with the rest of the elements. I wanted to keep the first bracket on the same line, but the rest of the elements go on the next line.

Comment: All of the above formats will be applied to the entire JAVA source file when I press Ctrl-Shift-F. My problem is based around generated method stubs.

Comment: I guess eclipse uses these settings because if you change formatter the way method is generated is changed so It uses the setting. Also check if `Fromattter`->`New Line` settings that `in empty method body ` is checked

Comment: It seems after a method stub has been generated, it automatically formats the stub to the custom format I wanted. I guess it is why the 2003 bug has been verified as fixed. The formatting has been delegated into a different process in the IDE. Heh!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this would appear to be a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32122), although that dates back to 2003. I found the most retarded way of getting the newline character inserted there however. You copy paste a newline from a text file (sheesh)

Comment: I tried that method, but Eclipse didn't register the carriage return, and still ended up with `{}` in the body of the generated method.